# .net rotateflip reduces file size

Tags: image, compression, drawing, save

I have a short snippet of code to rotate an image

```
Sub RotateImage(ByVal FilePath As String)
    Dim img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(FilePath)
    img.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone)
    img.Save("c:\test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    img.Dispose()
End Sub
```

For some reason, the new image is 758kb instead of 1.69 mb as the original.

Why is this and how can I fix this?

I do not want to compress the image, just rotate it.

other then that, I compared the properties in win explorer, and they all seem to be identical, including resolution. so what is actually happening?

Comment: Are you sure the original image is a jpg?

Comment: its extension is ".jpg", can it be something else? its directly from the camera.

Comment: have any ideas for me? anybody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because the image is recoded. I can not see anything in the documentation saying that [`RotateFlip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rotateflip.aspx) should be lossless.

A quick tour with Google gives [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/64116/Using-GDIplus-code-in-a-WPF-application-for-lossle.aspx) that you might try.

Comment: hi thanks. i didn't answer till now, cause i wanted to learn a bit about jpg and compression. something which im not very good at. you say rotateflip is not necessarily lossless compression. but can i make no compression at all? i dont want to compress in the first place. the code you link to, i have already tried in the past, but was giving me errors. i will now try again and see if i can contact the author. if you have anything to add, please do :-) !

Comment: @Yisman, JPEG images are compressed and when you change something in the image you need to redo the compression, at least for the edited parts. For 90° rotation there is this special lossless trick you can use, but that won't be applied if you just rotate the image and tries compresses the result. You need to use the magic trick. If you want to remove the compression, save as BMP or use a lossless compression like PNG. That will increase the filesize though.

Comment: thank you! its working now. it still reduces the file with a few kb. do you think that's a problem?